# parsing a sql string for integer values with multiple delimiters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parsing

I found some related examples here on SO, but not one that for this case specifically. Here goes:

I need to use SQL to parse data sourced from a flat file that is pipe delimited. One of the fields is sub-formatted as follows. My end state is to sum the integers within the field, but my question here is to see of ways to use a SQL SELECT to parse/extract JUST the integers. The pattern of the sub-formatting will always be where the desired integers will be preceded by a tilde (~) and followed by an asterisk (*). The number of sub fields may vary too (my example has 5, but there could more or less). The 4 char TAG name is of no importance.

So here is a sample:

```
|GADS~55.0*BILK~0.0*BOBB~81.0*HETT~32.0*IGGR~51.0|
```

From this example, all I would want for processing is the final number of 219. Again, I can work on the sum part as a further step; just interested in getting the numbers.

I know how to handle this quite easily with UNIX tools (ie AWK, sed, etc), but not in SQL. Any suggestions will help! Thanks!

Comment: What with the integers that appear in other pipe-sections? Do they need to be summed as well, together or separately?

Comment: Thanks trincot. Integers (actually all values) from other piped sections do not need any logic or arithmetic applied for this change. This is the only pipe delimited field that needs this.

Comment: I still don't get what should happen with a field that has this value `|GADS~55.0*BILK~0.0|BOBB~81.0*HETT~32.0|IGGR~51.0|` Should turn into one number or several? Which?

Comment: Sorry, I was presenting the question in a couple of steps. To answer your question, that field should turn into one number. The sum of those integers. For this example, the value would be 219.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will come back with 219:

- In Cut1 I let the string start with the first number.
- In Cut2 I cut the final pipe and add an asterisk
- In Splitted I replace the ~ with XML tags thus making it easy to split the string
- In the final Select the pure numbers are summed up...

Now the code

```
 DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100) = '|GADS~55.0*BILK~0.0*BOBB~81.0*HETT~32.0*IGGR~51.0|';

 WITH Cut1 AS
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX('~',@str,1)+1,1000) AS c1
)
,Cut2 AS
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(Cut1.c1,1,LEN(Cut1.c1)-1) + '*' AS c2 FROM Cut1
)
,Splitted AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(Cut2.c2,'~','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS AsXML FROM Cut2
)
SELECT SUM(CAST(SUBSTRING(numbers.value('.','varchar(100)'),1,CHARINDEX('*',numbers.value('.','varchar(100)'),1)-1) AS FLOAT))
FROM Splitted
CROSS APPLY AsXML.nodes('/x') AS the(numbers)
```

Comment: Wow, this is the best one yet. looked good in my testing, too. very scalable.

Comment: @sirabhorn, glad to read this! One hint (which is the same for the other aswer as well: You should be sure, that your strings do not contain XML-forbidden characters like `<, > and &`. If so, you'd have to escape them with `&lt; and &gt; and &amp;`

Answer (score 1):

Is it this what you want (it calculates the sum 219)? Sorry for the ugly formatting, but for sure you can make it "pretty" by yourself.

```
declare @Input varchar(255),
        @InputModified varchar(255)

set @Input = '|GADS~55.0*BILK~0.0*BOBB~81.0*HETT~32.0*IGGR~51.0|'


 SELECT 
@InputModified = 
 (
     CAST(CAST((
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, Number, 1)
            FROM master..spt_values
            WHERE Type='p' AND Number <= LEN(@Input) AND
            (
                SUBSTRING(@Input, Number, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' 
                or
                SUBSTRING(@Input, Number, 1) LIKE '~'
                or
                SUBSTRING(@Input, Number, 1) LIKE '.'
            )
            FOR XML Path(''))
        AS xml) AS varchar(MAX))
)


select sum(cast(Integers as float))
from
(
    SELECT 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Integers
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(@InputModified,'~','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
    )t
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
) Integers
where IsNumeric(Integers.Integers) = 1
```

Comment: Reboon - Thanks! that does the trick. And I tried with some of my other test data sets and it behaved as expected. I can work on making it more pretty, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

additional approach using recursive cte:

```
DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(255) 
SET @Input = '|GADS~55.0*BILK~0.0*BOBB~81.0*HETT~32.0*IGGR~51.0|'
;WITH cte ( n )
       AS ( SELECT   n = 1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT   n + 1
            FROM     cte
            WHERE    n <= LEN(@Input)
           )

 SELECT  SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT, val))
 FROM   (SELECT SUBSTRING(STUFF(@Input, 1, t.n, ''), 1,
                                PATINDEX('%[*|]%', STUFF(@Input, 1, t.n, '')) - 1) AS Val
         FROM cte AS t
         WHERE SUBSTRING(@Input, t.n, 
                         PATINDEX('%[*|]%', SUBSTRING(@Input, t.n, 99))) LIKE '~%[*|]'
         ) AS T
```

*test is* [**HERE**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/480239/split-string-and-sum-numeric-values)

Comment: Interesting, cool to see another way to do it, but my local run of this (and your test link) has a result set of 168, when it should be 219. Am I missing something? looks like this solution doesn't account for the last integer value (51.0) thanks

Comment: Yes, it's return 168 because I've inserted criteria for searching value exactly as in your question (`the desired integers will be *preceded by a tilde (~) and followed by an asterisk (*)*`), but the last integer value (51.0) does not followed by the asterisk `*`, that is why it has been ignored. I've updated my answer with searching values not only followed by an asterisk `*` but also followed by a pipe `|`, so now it's return desired output.

Comment: Good point! My specs needed that clarity, as my requirements do include needing the last value...and great followup solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to be different.Also I am not following any delimiter.
So not following any delimiter may be strength of this technique.

I just extract the first number from string then delete string from 0 till that number and so on.

So it is very clear that we can do it using recursive CTE,while loop and using row_number.

Here I have tried using Recursive CTE which may not be optimize,but sometime it is fun to be different.

```
DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(255) 
SET @Input = '|GADS~55.0*BILK~0.0*BOBB~81.0*HETT~32.0*IGGR~51.0|';
```

This line do the trick for me,

```
select Left(SubString(@Input, PatIndex('%[0-9.]%', @Input),8000),
PatIndex('%[^0-9.]%', SubString(@Input, 
PatIndex('%[0-9.]%', @Input), 8000) )-1)
```

Complete Script,

```
;With CTE as
(
Select @Input Input, Left(SubString(@Input, PatIndex('%[0-9.]%', @Input), 8000), PatIndex('%[^0-9.]%', SubString(@Input, PatIndex('%[0-9.]%', @Input), 8000) )-1) XX

union all

select cast(stuff(Input,1, charindex(XX,Input)+len(XX)-1,'') as varchar(255))
,Left(SubString(cast(stuff(Input,1, charindex(XX,Input)+len(XX)-1,'') as varchar(255)), PatIndex('%[0-9.]%', cast(stuff(Input,1, charindex(XX,Input)+len(XX)-1,'') as varchar(255))), 8000), PatIndex('%[^0-9.]%', SubString(cast(stuff(Input,1, charindex(XX,Input)+len(XX)-1,'') as varchar(255)), PatIndex('%[0-9.]%', cast(stuff(Input,1, charindex(XX,Input)+len(XX)-1,'') as varchar(255))), 8000) )-1)
from cte where len(input)>0

)

select sum(cast(XX as float)) from cte
where xx is not null or xx<>''
```